# How to handle git and react project for the first time?

Tags: reactjs, git, gitlab

I've installed a react project recently this way:

```
npx create-react-app projectName
```

When it successfully installed, apparently the git is also installed on it. Since there is `.git` directory exist in the root.

From the other side, I created a new project on Gitlab and connected it to the project this way:

```
git remote add origin http://gitlab.<domain>.com/myName/projectName.git
```

Now, I want to push a commit on the git named something like "Project Init". But there is no change detected when I run `git status`. So I cannot `add` and `commit` anything.

So, when I run `git push origin master` I get this error:

> hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

When I run `git pull origin master`,  get this error:

> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

I stuck in this part ..! What I have to do? In other word, how to synchronise the git and a react project created just now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to do it is to create new repo without "initial readme.md commit". Fast way is to `git push origin main --allow-unrelated-histories`. Or just simply use `--force` flag in push, but be careful with that

Comment: `--allow-unrelated-histories` is not a `git push` option, it's a `git merge` option (and thus passed through from `git pull`). I think you were suggesting pulling (= fetch and then merge) with the allow-unrelated-histories option, followed by pushing, which will often work; but probably the force-push method is better for this particular case (though we haven't quite been given enough information, so as you note, "be careful" :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the allow-unrelated-histories flag when pushing.